# error: ‘IGN_PROFILE’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, ros

In my code, I have checked twice all the braces are balanced. Indentation is 2 spaces. In spite of all of this, I am getting this weird compilation error

```
error: ‘IGN_PROFILE’ was not declared in this scope
```

My code

```
void amcl::PostUpdate(const ignition::gazebo::UpdateInfo &_info,ignition::gazebo::EntityComponentManager &_ecm)

{
  IGN_PROFILE("amcl::PostUpdate"); ---->Error in this line
  // Nothing left to do if paused.
   if (_info.paused)
  
   {
     return;

   }
   this->dataPtr->updateAmclPose();

}


bool amcl::updateAmclPose()

{
  IGN_PROFILE("amcl::updateAmclPose");  ---->Error in this line

   bool isok {false};

   try
        
   {
     if(tfBuffer_.canTransform(fixed_frame_, robot_frame_, ros::Time(0)))
        
     {

        read_transformation_ = tfBuffer_.lookupTransform(fixed_frame_, robot_frame_, ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(60.0));

        msg_.header.frame_id = fixed_frame_;
        msg_.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

        msg_.pose.pose.position.x = read_transformation_.transform.translation.x;
        msg_.pose.pose.position.y = read_transformation_.transform.translation.y;
        msg_.pose.pose.position.z = read_transformation_.transform.translation.z;

        msg_.pose.pose.orientation.x = read_transformation_.transform.rotation.x;
        msg_.pose.pose.orientation.y = read_transformation_.transform.rotation.y;
        msg_.pose.pose.orientation.z = read_transformation_.transform.rotation.z;
        msg_.pose.pose.orientation.w = read_transformation_.transform.rotation.w;
     }
      
     isok = true;
        
   } 
  
   catch(const tf2::TimeoutException & e)
        
   {

     ROS_ERROR_STREAM(ros::this_node::getName() << " " << __func__ <<" timeout exception: " << e.what());    
        
     return isok;
    
   }
        
   catch(const tf2::TransformException & e)
        
   {
        
     ROS_ERROR_STREAM(ros::this_node::getName() << " " << __func__ <<" transform exception: " << e.what());
        
     return isok;
    
   }

   return isok;

}
```

PS: I have marked the lines throwing this error in the code. I know this is a kinda dumb question but I have tried everything and still can't get rid of this error.

Can anyone help, please?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are missing `void IGN_PROFILE(char const*) { }` in the code.

Comment: Since we can't see a declaration for `IGN_PROFILE` in the given code, I have to agree with the compiler. Maybe you forgot to include a header?

Comment: @user4581301 you are an absolute legend. I forgot the header. Sehr Danke. Thanks.